What is a second oversize Hi-Lok fastener?
Many structural repair guidelines specify to use a 2nd oversize fastener e.g.3/16 second oversize Hi-Lok, when replacing an existing fastener in an assembly.
What does "second oversize" mean in "3/16 second oversize Hi-Lok?

When a hole has been damaged, its diameter is increased to get a new clean hole and recover the structural integrity. This requires the use of an oversize fastener (alternatively a sleeve).
3/16″ is a reference to standard diameter and "second" means the second increased diameter. From Jet-Tek catalog, the diameter is increased by steps of 1/64″:




The standard diameter is ⌀ = 3/16″ (or 6/32″ or 12/64″).

The 1st oversize (+1/64″) is ⌀ = 13/64″.

The 2nd oversize (+1/32″) is ⌀ = 7/32″ (14/64″).


The oversize diameter is always between two nominal diameters. The part number is often common to the standard and oversize fasteners, with a unique character representing the oversize.

+1 Correct, except that I don’t think the 3/16” can be referring to the increase in diameter - that would be huge, representing more than the largest step between standard sizes. More likely “3/16 second oversize” refers to a 3/16” nominal shank + two oversize steps, i.e. .21875” shank.

You're right, corrected. Thanks.

How do you "damage a hole"? :-)
